# Disable vibration on Xbox One controller (on PC)

Tags: pc, controllers

I'm using Xbox One controller with a PC. I'm not big fan of a vibration (rumble) feature, and I always disable it in all games, there such option is available. But still it vibrates every time PC is turning on. Is there any way to diable Xbox One controller vibration completely on a PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to turn the vibration off on a PC. Only games have the option to turn it off.

Answer (score 6):

Since 2018, it is possible to turn off vibration on a normal Xbox One Controller. Download the Xbox Accessories app from the Microsoft Store. Then, plug in your controller, open the app, and select Configure.

Create a new profile, and click Edit. Untick the Turn On Vibration box, and save the profile. To activate it, select Slot 1 from the "Slot" Drop-down menu. Done.

[image: Screenshot from Xbox Accessories App showing where the no vibration option is]

Comment: I followed the instructions but I had a connection issue with the controller, even if it worked in any game. After hundreds of red pages, I finally got it to work after I have installed Xbox Identity Provider from the Microsoft Store. Maybe someday, someone will read this, who knows..

Answer (score 0):

If you own an [**Xbox Elite Wireless Controller**](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/controllers/elite-wireless-controller), you can disable vibrations on a per-controller per-profile basis through the [**Xbox Accessories**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/xbox-accessories/9nblggh30xj3) app on Windows 10 or Xbox One.

Simply create a new configuration or edit existing ones, and set whichever vibration sliders to 0 you want. Don't forget to save the configurations to either profile 1 or 2 on your controller.

While the sliders for "Left trigger" and "Right trigger" are self explanatory, the ones for "Left main" and "Right main" are a little bit misleading. The "Left main" slider controls the big motors for rough, powerful, low-frequency vibrations. The "Right main" slider controls the small motors for weak, high-frequency vibrations.

The Xbox Accessories app can (currently) *not* be used to configure regular Xbox One controllers.